# My .sort() is only sorting the added values from my input box? why is this

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, sorting

So i created a input box to add a value to an array, however when it sorts the array it only sorts the values from the input box, not the whole array. i messed around with it but nothing seems to work.

```
<script>

var Arrays = ["Printer", "Tablet", "Router", "Smart phone", "Motherboard",     "Hard drive"];
document.getElementById("beef").innerHTML = Arrays;


function displayMessage() {
var userInput = document.hey.firstname.value; 
document.getElementById("pie").innerHTML = "The user entered: " + userInput +  "<br>";

Arrays.push(userInput);

document.getElementById("pie").innerHTML = Arrays;
} 

function count() {
document.getElementById("counting").innerHTML =
Arrays.length;
}

function sort() { 
document.getElementById("pie").innerHTML = Arrays;
Arrays.sort();
}   





</script>
<body>
```

## JavaScript Arrays

```
<br>
<form name="hey">
Enter value:
<br>
<input type="" name="firstname" value="">
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="displayMessage()">Add to list</button>
</form>

<p id="pie"></p>

<br>

<p id="beef"></p>

<br>

<button type="button" onclick="count();sort();">Click to count and sort</button>

<br>

<p id="counting"></p>
<br>
<p id="sorting"></p>
<br>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I really did not get what is getting sort or not, however, I noticed an issue and listing down below.

You need to update your `sort` function so as you are sorting first and then setting the value in html.

```
function sort() { 
   Arrays.sort(); // need to sort first
   document.getElementById("pie").innerHTML = Arrays;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple problems here. First of all, as other comment says, you need to sort before writing the result. Second thing is, you probably entered small letters as user input, but javascript array sort is case sensitive and words starting with capital letters are ordered before words with small letters. You will need to add custom functionality to the sort function if you're willing to ignore casing. You can try and replace your sort function with this:

```
function sort() {
    Arrays.sort(function(a, b) {

        if (a.toLowerCase() < b.toLowerCase())
            return -1;

        if (a.toLowerCase() > b.toLowerCase())
            return 1;

        return 0;
    });

    document.getElementById('beef').innerHTML = Arrays;
}
```

On the side note, you're overwriting `The user entered..` sentence inside your `displayMessage` method. You probably want to change `pie` for `beef` there.
Same thing can be applied inside the sort method. Finally, code should look like this:

```js
var Arrays = ['Printer', 'Tablet', 'Router', 'Smart phone', 'Motherboard', 'Hard drive'];
document.getElementById("beef").innerHTML = Arrays;

function displayMessage() {
    var userInput = document.hey.firstname.value;
    document.getElementById('pie').innerHTML = "The user entered: " + userInput +  "<br>";
    Arrays.push(userInput);
    document.getElementById('beef').innerHTML = Arrays;
} 

function count() {
    document.getElementById('counting').innerHTML = Arrays.length;
}

function sort() {
    Arrays.sort(function(a, b) {
        if (a.toLowerCase() < b.toLowerCase())
            return -1;
        if (a.toLowerCase() > b.toLowerCase())
            return 1;
        return 0;
    });
    document.getElementById('beef').innerHTML = Arrays;
}
```

```html
<br>
  <form name="hey">
    Enter value:<br>
    <input type="" name="firstname" value=""><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="displayMessage();">Add to list</button>
  </form>
  <p id="pie"></p>
<br>
  <p id="beef"></p>
<br>
  <button type="button" onclick="count();sort();">Click to count and sort</button>
<br>
  <p id="counting"></p>
<br>
  <p id="sorting"></p>
<br>
```